# Diffuse texture baking from High-poly FBX to Low-poly

Tags: texturing

I have imported an FBX file into Blender with a high poly model. I have to convert this to a low poly model and bake the texture.

The object itself I have simplified with the help of Retopology. But now I have problems with the bake of the texture. In the material shading the original high-poly with the texture is displayed in a sore bar. However, this does not seem to have a UV map, at least the seams cannot be displayed.

For my object I have created a UV map. I also made a cage object out of the simple object to bake the texture. But when I want to bake the texture, more precisely the diffuse map, I get only a black image. Unfortunately, I don't know what to do and it would be a bit more urgent with the object.

Comment: It would help to see the material. A common reason for a black bake result is the use of SSS and Metallic. You need to set them to 0 in the Principled BSDF node (if you have one).

Comment: Hi!
I have now solved the problem. I have created a completely new material, so it worked.

For test reasons, I had tried to bake the texture for the original in the same shader, and also got a black texture. After that came the idea that maybe somewhere in the shader was the problem.
I don't know if the problem originated already, or if it crept in when exporting the file, I can't check that, because it's not my own file. But with this it worked wonderfully.

So simple, and yet it kept me from working for almost a complete day.